# Bootstrap list is not collapsing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
 <li class="panel panel-default dropdown organization">
  <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#dropdown-reg">
    <span class="icon fa fa-plus"></span><span class="title">Add                    Masters</span>
  </a>
  <div id="dropdown-reg" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><span class="icon fa fa-tasks"></span>Add         Claim</a>
        </li>
        <li class="panel panel-default dropdown organization">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dropdown-reg1">
            <span class="icon fa fa-tasks"></span><span class="title">Add Policy</span>
          </a>
          <div id="dropdown-reg1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="${path}/master/policy/addpolicycovertypes">Cover Type</a></li>
                <li><a href="${path}/master/policy/addpolicycoverterms">Cover Terms</a></li>
                <li><a href="${path}/master/policy/addpolicynature">Nature</a></li>
                <li><a href="${path}/master/policy/addconveyance">Conveyance</a></li>
                <li><a href="${path}/master/policy/addpackage">Package</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="groupsActive"><a href="#">Upcoming</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

When extended the Add Policy list it is not working.

Comment: the addPolicy list is collapsing correctly....no issue found

Comment: jsfiddle showing your code working correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/humotrj0/119/ make sure you are including the latest js and css from bootstrap

Comment: <li>addmaster main list inside of the i wrote add claim and add policy inside of the add policy list is there . problem is when i press add policy it is closing means it is going to main menu that is add master

Answer (score 0):

Everything work great, just click [here (bootply)](http://www.bootply.com/J8w37sLu3u) and see.

Also, ensure yourself that you imported all the bootstrap libraries correctly, and like haxxxton has said,  make sure you are also including the latest js and css from bootstrap.

In fact, in the head you can import the bootstrap css library and in the footer (just before the closed body tag `</body>`), don't forget to import the libraries of jQuery and Bootstrap Javascript (put jQuery before Bootstrap), just like this :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>SO</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div >
        <li class="panel panel-default dropdown organization">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#dropdown-reg">
                <span class="icon fa fa-plus"></span><span class="title">Add                    Masters</span>
            </a>
            <div id="dropdown-reg" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><span class="icon fa fa-tasks"></span>Add         Claim</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="panel panel-default dropdown organization">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dropdown-reg1">
                                <span class="icon fa fa-tasks"></span><span class="title">Add Policy</span>
                            </a>
                            <div id="dropdown-reg1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                        <li><a href="${path}/master/policy/addpolicycovertypes">Cover Type</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="${path}/master/policy/addpolicycoverterms">Cover Terms</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="${path}/master/policy/addpolicynature">Nature</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="${path}/master/policy/addconveyance">Conveyance</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="${path}/master/policy/addpackage">Package</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="groupsActive"><a href="#">Upcoming</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Working One for you.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        <span class="icon fa fa-plus"></span><span class="title"> Add Masters</span>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="icon fa fa-tasks"></span> Add Claim</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                <span class="icon fa fa-tasks"></span> Add Policy
                            </a>
                            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                        <li><a href="${path}/master/policy/addpolicycovertypes">Cover Type</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="${path}/master/policy/addpolicycoverterms">Cover Terms</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="${path}/master/policy/addpolicynature">Nature</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="${path}/master/policy/addconveyance">Conveyance</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="${path}/master/policy/addpackage">Package</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Upcoming</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle Link to Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xk9e6ghz/)

Comment: <li>AddMaster</li>

Comment: @Rajesh what <li>AddMaster</li> ?